Is there an equivalent of boat fenders for cars?
I want to have on my car (a Mini Cooper) a component or a piece that protects the vehicle in case of little impacts in urban streets if someone touches my vehicle while parking his...
Like an iPhone case to protect the phone against little impacts...
Is it currently existing ?

There seems to be two kinds of car park damage: a) people dinging your car when they open the door, b) scrapes near the wheel arches when they misjudge the clearance when turning into the bay. As far as opening doors go, I don't think you can do much about other people because the ding might be anywhere along the side of your car. What you can do is protect against damaging other cars with a buffer strip near the edge of your doors. In the old days you could use a rubber trim around the door edge, but not now: doors are more close fitting.

There are many products; front 'urban jungle black, chrome, stainless brush guards, front/rear license plate frames as rubber 'bumpers, horizontal door strips in various widths and thicknesses, vanity door bumpers with oem logos, etc. Perhaps taking up two parking spots (and suffer the wrath) or parking well away from main spots to minimize door dings.

For lack of a better term, I used "automotive body protectors" on the search engine. The return was as expected, in various forms.
One of the many returns is Brandsport with many different sizes and styles. You can find black, chrome, carbon fiber appearing, perhaps more.

Image from linked site.
Not too far off from the phone case description, in that it creates a rebound strip to absorb dings.
Note that nothing is really going to protect an automobile body panels from a full-on contact from a passing vehicle. These products are aimed at protection from door dings and the like.
A parking driver making contact with your car will only recognize that contact is made when the damage would exceed that provided by these protective strips.
